# pass a property to JDBC post processor in Jmeter

Tags: java, jmeter

I am trying to pass a property, which is set in a JSR223 step,  in JDBC post processor like below but I get `No such property: some_id for class: script xxx`

```
Select t.column1, t.column2 from someTable t where t.some_id = '${_groovy(_property(some_id),)}' ;
```

I am setting and then checking `some_id` in a JSR223 PostProcessor placed just before JDBC  like this

`props.put("some_id", someMethod(someParam))`

`log.info(props.getProperty("some_id")); //prints some_id`

from above, it seems property is set correctly , so why does it say no such property. Is what I am doing not possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either just go for [__P() function](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__P) like:

```
${__P(some_id,)}
```

or use the correct syntax for the [__groovy() function](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__groovy) like:

```
${__groovy(props.get('some_id'),)}
```

If you're uncertain regarding proper syntax for this or that function - consider using the [Function Helper Dialog](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#function_helper)

More information on JMeter Functions concept: [Apache JMeter Functions - An Introduction](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/apache-jmeter-functions-introduction)